# Visual proof of $\frac{1}{1 \times 2} + \frac{1}{2 \times 3} + \frac{1}{3 \times 4} + \frac{1}{4 \times 5} + ... = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, visualization, telescopic-series

I am trying to find a visual way of proving that $$\frac{1}{1 \times 2} + \frac{1}{2 \times 3} + \frac{1}{3 \times 4} + \frac{1}{4 \times 5} + ... = 1$$

I am familiar with algebraic methods of proving this formulas (such as using a telescoping sum) - this is **not** what I am looking for.

I was thinkng about each term as representing the areas of rectangles (see image) but I am unsure about how to use this to prove the above result.

[image]

Comment: I have edited the title and the question to reflect that.

Comment: It may be unsolved at least in a sense. Research problem 2.37 in *Concrete Mathematics* by R. L. Graham, D. E. Knuth, and O. Patashnik: “Will all the $ 1/k $ by $ 1/(k + 1) $ rectangles, for $ k \geq 1 $, fit together inside a $ 1 $ by $ 1 $ square?” Comments by the authors: “RLG thinks they probably won't fit; DEK thinks they probably will; OP is not committing himself.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists a visual proof of this sum without the use of rectangles and areas. I saw this in *Proofs Without Words*. I give two explanations, first using coordinate geometry, second using similarity of right triangles.

**Explanation using coordinate geometry :**

Consider the lines intercepting the axes at $(n,0)$ and $(0,1)$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$

[image]

Equation of lines is
$$\frac{x}{n}+\frac{y}{1}=1$$

They make an intercept of $1-\dfrac{1}{n}$ on $x=1$ line. Hence length of the colored segments is
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

which are the terms in our sum. As $n$ becomes arbitrarily large, these lines approach the horizontal $y=1$ line. Clearly the sum of colored segments tends to unity.

**Explanation using similarity of triangles :**

We have right triangles with both sides on axes with legs $1$ and $n$. All the hypotenuse intersect with the colored vertical line to produce similar triangles with base $n-1$. Thus the similarity ratio is $\dfrac{n-1}{n}$ and the vertical leg is also of length $\dfrac{n-1}{n}\cdot 1=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Same as above, each differently colored segment has length $\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and as number of triangles becomes arbitrarily large, our sum approaches value of $1$.

Comment: Clever arrangement !